# What kind of web framework is this?

Tags: web, frameworks

I've seen the layout in the following link a few times now, and they all look very similar.  Is this a template or a framework that people are using?  The reason I ask is that I am looking to build simple web apps but do not have a knack for the design aspect of it.

[Link 1](http://kegberry.kegbot.org/images/screenshot-taps-admin.png)

Comment: That can be made with many frameworks, but quite possibly it's Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely used framework is Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

You may find some alternatives here: http://modernweb.com/2014/02/17/8-bootstrap-alternatives/